# Choose right library version

Tags: gcc, linker

I have a project which uses libibverbs. I have to compile this project on a server to run it there. The server has libibverbs installed system-wide, but unfortunately it doesn't support a feature which I need.

I decided to compile and use my own version of libibverbs, which has the corresponding feature. So I compiled the library, installed it to my home directory, and updated following environment variables: PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

Now I have to compile my project. First I call configure and it fails with following error message:

```
conftest.c:(.text.startup+0x7): undefined reference to `ibv_open_xrc_domain'
```

This is the symbol, which is missing in the system-wide version, but is present in the version I installed. First entry in LIBRARY_PATH is the path to the new libibversion, so I expected it is going to be used first, but it seems that the old version is used anyway.

Compilation command which ./configure uses, contains flag -L/libibverbs/1.1.4/lib, which points to the directory with the new library version. This flag goes just after -L/usr/lib/../lib64 which point to the directory, with system-wide libibverbs

If I put -L with new version in the end of command, the conftest compiles successfully.

To be clear following fails: https://gist.github.com/planetA/a421669269b14e69026c53f56fa45b2b

And following works:
https://gist.github.com/planetA/3b0e22bf6aca3a1c67f30bfa3666d9a8

Could you help me to enforce picking the new version of the library in a way that configure catches it?

Comment: You will have to change the `configure.ac` of the project from which the `./configure` script is built, and you will have to post it if you want reliable advice on how to do that.

Comment: But why the new library is not captured from LIBRARY_PATH? Is it some specified behavior? Or do I do something completely strange?

Comment: There's no -L/home/anything in the first gist. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: this directory is in LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` specifies directories to be searched, before the
defaults, for a library that is to be loaded in a process at *runtime*.
It does not affect the directories that are searched for a library
in order to link it at *buildtime*.

The linker searches for libraries in the directories that are specified
with the `-L`*dir* option in its commandline, before it searches its
default directories. Your `configure` script tests whether it can find a `libibverbs` library in the *linker's* search directories that defines the function
`ibv_open_xrc_domain`, and fails because it cannot. The value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does
not matter to this test.

For GNU `make`, the `-L`-options it should pass to the linker
are conventionally specified in the environment variable `LDFLAGS`. GNU `autoconf` - which
generates your `configure` script - follows this convention. `autoconf` generates
the `configure` script from the project's `configure.ac` file.

So, if your want your modified package to generate a generate a `configure`
script such that running `./configure` will in turn generate makefiles
in which `-L`*/my/library/version/is/here* is passed to the linker then
you need to modify the project's `configure.ac` like:

```
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/my/library/version/is/here"
```

and you need to do this in the `configure.ac` before it runs the test for
the `libibverbs` library. After making this change you will need to reconfigure
the package by running `autoreconf` in the project directrory, to regenerate
the `configure` script.

If you don't want to change the `configure.ac` like this then you can achieve the same
effect by:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/my/library/version/is/here"
```

or:

```
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/my/library/version/is/here"
... # in same shell or a subshell
./configure
```

Then until the next time you run the `configure` script the project's makefiles
will pass `-L/my/library/version/is/here` to the linker. But the next time
you run `./configure` you must remember to set `LDFLAGS` in the same way, or
the regenerated makefiles will revert to the default behaviour.

Comment: Both approaches ./configure LDFLAGS=... and setting LDFLAGS before calling autoconf work. Thank you!